# c++ boost пытается подключить библиотеку не той разрядности

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, boost

Установив boost для конкретного использования boost.python, я столкнулся с проблемой при сборке моей первой (та даже любой) программы. Ошибка линкера (1104), который пытается открыть файл boost_python_39-vc142-mt-gd-x32-1_75.lib, в то время когда у меня есть только boost_python_39-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_75.lib. Пробовал b2 stage link=static link=shared --with-python, устанавливает библиотеки только для 64битной системы, напомню что буст ищет 32 битную. Переустановки, конфигурации не помогают, все папки и пути до папок и к заголовкам указаны верно. Как мне сделать так чтоб буст искал библиотеки 64 разрядности?

Comment: Следует собирать свою программу в 64 бит.

Comment: Каким образом мне нужно это сделать? Я использую Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Следует выставить текущее Solution Platform на x64. Видимо у вас стоит x86 (win32)

Comment: Когда я меняю на х64 студия перестает видеть файлы boost'а. В чем проблема?

Comment: Видимо вы не задали в настройках проекта пути. Настройки отдельные для каждой комбинации конфигурации и платформы решения.

Comment: Я разобрался, большое спасибо вам, неделю не мог разобраться в чем проблема. Спасибо большое еще раз.

Comment: Еще вам стоит разобраться с работой msbuild. А то многие для каждого нового проекта каждый раз РУКАМИ заполняют настройки и потом ноют в интернетах, что VS неудобная.